# Vercel CLI deployment failed: "socket hang up"

Tags: svelte, vercel, sveltekit

I'm trying to deploy my SvelteKit project with the Vercel CLI (24.0.0, note that this also occurs on 23.0.1 in my experience). The project already has an existing deployment on Vercel.

I do `vercel deploy --prod`, but the process will hang until eventually it throws this error: `Error! request to https://api.vercel.com/v13/now/deployments failed, reason: socket hang up`

Edit: Sometimes it throws a different error: `Error! FetchError: request to https://api.vercel.com/v2/now/files failed, reason: socket hang up`

I've used this method to deploy projects in the past - always worked.

I've tried all of these, but with the same result:

- Attempted to deploy a different (also existing) project.
- Attempted to deploy a Svelte (not SvelteKit) project.
- Attempted to deploy a new project with a different Vercel account.
- Attempted to deploy the project on a different internet connection.
- Clear local git cache with `git rm -r --cached` before deploying.

How do I get past this issue to deploy my project? Or is this a global issue with Vercel that is out of my control?

Comment: in the meantime, I'm deploying my projects to production on Vercel simply by linking the project's GitHub repository instead. seems like a permanent alternative for me